# Access list of @overload signatures

Tags: python

It is possible to get signature of a function in python with `inspect.signature`.

```
from typing import overload
import inspect

class Foo:
    @overload
    def foo(x: int, y: float): ...
    @overload
    def foo(y: float): ...
    def foo(a, b=None):
        if b is None:
            x, y = 1, a
        else:
            x, y = a, b
        return y / x

print(inspect.signature(Foo.foo))  # (a, b=None)
```

Is there any way to also see signatures of all overloads of such function?
In this example, I want to get a list `[inspect.Signature(x: int, y: float), inspect.Signature(y: float)]` or something close to it.

Comment: side-note: trying to hack with `mypy` tricks, your methods are missing `self`. I couldn't get very far, but mypy seems like a potential tool candidate for your task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as @AKX mentioned, there is no way to get the signatures of the overloaded method during runtime from the inspection of this method...

But! We can inspect the source code of the class. So one hacky solution could be:

```
source_lines, _ = inspect.getsourcelines(Foo)

signatures = []
for l in zip(source_lines):
    if 'def foo(' in l:
        signatures.append(l.split('(')[1].split(')')[0])

print(signatures)
```

For your example, this produces:

```
['x: int, y: float', 'y: float', 'a, b=None']
```

This code looks directly into the source code of the class and parses it.

If you only want overloads, then you'd need to check for `@overload` as well:

```
source_lines, _ = inspect.getsourcelines(Foo)

signatures = []
for d, f in zip(source_lines, source_lines[1:]):
    if '@overload' in d and 'def foo(' in f:
        signatures.append(f.split('(')[1].split(')')[0])

print(signatures)
```

```
['x: int, y: float', 'y: float']
```

*This is obviously not a fail-proof solution. For instance, this would fail if the signature is divided into multiple lines or contains parentheses (for example tuples or function calls in default values).*

Answer (score 4):

[Before Python 3.11 is released with this PR that adds `typing.get_overloads()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/31716), not at runtime, because `@overload` does nothing to `foo`, it's just a decorator that type checkers understand.

Comment: To be precise, `@overload` replaces the function with the function that raises `NotImplementedError`. But you are right, all the `foo`s except the last one are lost at runtime

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Yes, but when using `@overload`, you end up overwriting the replaced function with the actual implementation anyway.